# What is an example for the mean-value theorem to fail to hold for differentiable functions $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ if $m \geq 2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We know that for any integer $n \geq 1$ and $m=1$, the mean-value theorem holds for differentiable functions $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Nevertheless, what is an example for the mean-value theorem to fail to hold for differentiable functions $\mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ if $m \geq 2$ is an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = (x(x-1), x^2(x-1))$. Then $f(0) = f(1) = (0,0)$, and we are looking for a point $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f(0)-f(1) = f'(c)$.

However $[f'(c)]_1 = 0 $ **iff** $c={1 \over 2}$ and 
$[f'(c)]_2 = 0$ **iff** $c \in \{0, {2 \over 3} \} $,
so no such point exists.

Comment: Thanks. But what does the notation $[ \cdot ]_{i}$ with $i = 1,2$ mean?

Comment: The first and second component of $f'(c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any randomly chosen $f= (f_1, f_2) \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ will not satisfy the mean value theorem. Indeed, it is higly unlikely that the $c_1$, $c_2$ that work for $f_1$, $f_2$ will coincide.

For instance $f(x) = (x^2, x^3)$ for the interval $[0,1]$.